# Sending a file and a string using MultiPartEntity in Android to server

Tags: java, android, client-server, multipartentity

I have an Android app from which I can select a video and select an option from a drop down. I want to send both of these to the server for analysis and get back the results. This is the code.

Android app

> MultiPartEntity entity = new MultiPartEntity ();
>   entity.addPart("option", new StringBody(selectedOption));
>   entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(sourceFile));
>
> httppost.setEntity(entity); HttpResponse response =
>   httpclient.execute(httppost);

Server code

> if request.method == 'POST':
>       if 'option' not in request.files:
>           return 'No option selected'

On the server, when I get a POST request, I'm checking whether 'file' and 'option' are present. But I find only file is present and not the option. What am I missing out here?

Comment: your android code seems to be OK. how do you check if they are present on the Server?

Comment: @omid I have edited the question to include server code also. Thank you.

Comment: can see your code in server for checking both file and option?